# How can I reduce NTFS system volume size beyond the limit of half?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I have Windows 8.1 installed exclusively on 1Tb volume. Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the other disk and want to access this big drive in read-write mode. However, Windows placed it's `hiberfil.sys` file onto it thus preventing me to mount it in rw mode. I tried to disable Windows quick boot feature (worked in Win8) but it seems not working.

So I decided to reduce `C:` size and create shared partition but faced with another problem: NTFS has a copy of allocation table in the middle of the disk and Windows doesn't want to move it. So I can only free up to 470~ Gb when I need about 840 Gb for the share and 160 Gb for `C:`.

I tried to repartition with Paragon Partition Manager and Acronis Disk Director. I tried to use Gparted. All of them failed. So I wander if method of resizing NTFS partition beyond the half does exist or  I need to reinstall Windows to achieve the desired result.

I don't want to reinstall Windows, so I hope someone advise me a good working partition tool or the method to unlock the drive.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know a solution further shrink your partition. But removing the hiberfil.sys is possible. Disabling the quick boot feature is just half the deal. You also need to **disable hibernation**. You can to this with this command (you need to be in a console with admin rights):

```
powercfg.exe -h off
```

This should remove the hibernation file.

BTW: I usually use [this partition program](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm). But I never had to shrink the partition to more than half the size.

Comment: Thanks! Both of your advices were helpful: I successfully shrunk the partition `C:` and was able to mount it in Ubuntu ^_^.